# Information bar transitioning to menubar on mobile site

Tags: menu, instructions

When  a user first visits my discussion site (designed for a mobile platform), I am using a long bar to contain first-time instructions.
[image: instruction bar]

After they complete the registration process, this area transitions to a menubar because a registered user should no longer need instructions but rather a menu to navigate the.

[image: menu bar]

Is this an effective user experience tool or is it confusing? Is the appearance not unified? How can I improve this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the screens, I'd have to say that it *probably* is good ux.

Giving users options that they can't use during registration is counter-productive, so hiding them to keep the user focused shouldn't have any drawbacks.